# SQL Query - first and last row, when end date is a start date for next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with

```
      MeetPointID   MeetPointName   date      ZoneStartTime         ZoneStopTime                Driver    DriverCode    Car                CarPlate
        12590           123      2018-06-12   2018-06-12 15:18:44   2018-06-12 15:19:24         Nowak Jan   NULL    K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
        12590           123      2018-06-12   2018-06-12 15:19:24   2018-06-12 15:24:45         Nowak Jan   NULL    K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
        12590           123      2018-06-12   2018-06-12 15:24:45   2018-06-12 15:25:05         Nowak Jan   NULL    K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
        260832          345      2018-06-12   2018-06-12 15:17:44   2018-06-12 15:19:24         Nowak Jan   NULL    K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
        260832          345      2018-06-12   2018-06-12 15:19:24   2018-06-12 15:24:45         Nowak Jan   NULL    K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
        260832          345      2018-06-12   2018-06-12 15:24:45   2018-06-12 15:27:05         Nowak Jan   NULL    K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
```

Table is showing entering and leaving time from some zones. I want to merge all rows, where MeetPointId is the same, and where ZoneStopTime is the same as next row ZoneStartTime. What I want to get is a table like below:

```
      MeetPointID   MeetPointName   date     ZoneStartTime        ZoneStopTime          Driver     DriverCode   Car                     CarPlate
         12590          123      2018-06-12  2018-06-12 15:18:44  2018-06-12 15:25:05   Nowak Jan  NULL         K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
         260832         345      2018-06-12  2018-06-12 15:17:44  2018-06-12 15:24:45   Nowak Jan   NULL        K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
```

What I have now is:

```
SELECT

ID as MeetPointID
,MeetPointName
,CONVERT(date, t.StartTime) as data
,min(t.StartTime) as ZoneStartTime
,max(t.StopTime) as ZoneStopTime
/*,iif(
max(t.NextStartTime) = max(StopTime), max(t.NextStartTime), max(StopTime)
)as ZoneStopTime*/

,t.Driver as Driver
,DriverCode
,t.Car as Car
,CarPlate

from 
 (
  Select 
amp.ID,
rza.StartTime,
rza.StopTime,
rsa.MainActivityID,

iif((rza.StopTime = LAST_VALUE(rza.StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY rsa.MainActivityID  ORDER BY CONVERT(date, rza.StopTime) asc)),
 LAST_VALUE(rza.StartTime) OVER(PARTITION BY rsa.MainActivityID  ORDER BY CONVERT(date, rza.StopTime) asc),

 rza.StopTime
)as NextStartTime

,ad.DriverLastName + ' ' + ad.DriverFirstName as Driver
,ad.DriverCode
,ac.CarPlate + ' ' + ac.CarBrand + ' ' + ac.CarModel as Car
,ac.CarPlate
,amp.MeetPointName

FROM
RPT_SUB_ACTIVITY rsa
JOIN RPT_ZONE_ACTIVITY rza on rza.SubActivityID= rsa.ID
JOIN RPT_ZoneActivityMeetPoints rzamp on rza.ID = rzamp.ZoneActivityID
JOIN APP_MEET_POINTS amp on rzamp.MeetPointsID=amp.ID
JOIN GPS_DEVICE gd on rsa.DeviceID = gd.DeviceID
JOIN APP_DRIVER ad on gd.DriverID = ad.DriverID
JOIN APP_CAR ac on ac.CarID = gd.CarID

WHERE
rza.DeviceID in (select * from dbo.fnList2Table(@DeviceIDList))
AND CONVERT(date, rza.StartTime) >= @StartDate
AND CONVERT(date, rza.StartTime) <= @StopDate
and rsa.TypeActivity in (1,2)
--and amp.ID = 12590
) t 

GROUP BY
ID
,MainActivityID
,MeetPointName
,CONVERT(date, StartTime)
,t.Driver
,DriverCode
,t.Car
,CarPlate

ORDER BY
ID, 
CONVERT(date, StartTime)
,ZoneStartTime
```

But this sql query is using ID's, which are not the same for the rows, so I'am able only to merge some of them.

Comment: can you post the sample data that you are unable to merge ?

Comment: I'm working exactly on data from the first table I posted. There are some additional ID's, but they are not letting me to merge rows, because they are different to each other.

Comment: Dont you want zonestop time for meetpointid 260832 = 2018-06-12 15:27:05  ???

Comment: And can you post some examples where zonestoptime is not like zonestarttime for next row?

Comment: My mistake, ZoneStopTime for meetpointid 260832 should be 2018-06-12 15:27:05.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Please check data below:

```
MeetPointID   StartTime               StopTime              MeetPointName   Driver      DriverCode  Car                     CarPlate
12590         2018-06-13 22:23:48     2018-06-13 22:24:29   123             Nowak Jan   NULL        K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
12590         2018-06-13 22:24:29     2018-06-13 22:24:57   123             Nowak Jan   NULL        K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
12590         2018-06-13 22:28:42     2018-06-13 22:30:33   123             Nowak Jan   NULL        K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
```

And this should give me a result of:

```
MeetPointID   StartTime               StopTime              MeetPointName   Driver      DriverCode  Car                     CarPlate
12590         2018-06-13 22:23:48     2018-06-13 22:24:57   123             Nowak Jan   NULL        K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
12590         2018-06-13 22:28:42     2018-06-13 22:30:33   123             Nowak Jan   NULL        K1ZORRO PEŻAK EXPERT    K1ZORRO
```